# Can Caitlyn's Yordle trap stop Master Yi while he is meditating?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been wondering for a while but haven't got the chance to see or try it in person but Can Caitlyn's Yordle trap stop/interrupt Master Yi while he is Meditating?

Given that Master Yi is not on highlander status and Cait freshly put a trap on him while he is meditating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Yordle Trap is a [rooting CC](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Types_of_Crowd_Control#Root) which does not stop channeled abilities or attacks.

Although it doesn't stop his Meditate it will prevent him from using Alpha Strike while rooted, so it will still be helpful in taking down Master Yi once his Meditate ends.

Highlander also only stops slows so I'm not sure what that has to do with this situation.

Comment: The only thing Highlander prevents is slows. Roots, snares, stuns, knockups/knockbacks, and other movement-impairing effects will affect him as normal. (For example, one of the funniest interactions is using Fiddlestick's Fear on an ulting Yi. Normally the fear would slow down the champion and make them walk slowly away... but since Yi can't be slowed, he'll run away from Fiddlesticks at high speed. It's very amusing.)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully for me, a Master Yi player, it doesn't!

Yi's Meditate can only be interrupted by a hard crowd control like a stun or knock-up. Cait's Yordle Trap only keeps people from moving.

To complete my answer, here are all the effects that can interrupt Yi's Meditate:

- Knock-ups (Blitzcrank's Power Fist E)
- Taunt (Ahri's Charm E, Rammus's
  Frenzying Taunt E)
- Fear (Fiddlestick's E)
- Silence (Soraka's Equinox E)
- Stasis (Bard's Tempered Fate R)
- Stun (Pantheon's Aegis of Zeonia W)
- Suppression (Warwick's Infinite Duress R)

As @VanBuzzKill pointed out, Rooting is not one of them

You can find more informations on crowd controls [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Types_of_Crowd_Control).

Comment: What do you mean by "bump"? knock-up?

Comment: By bump I mean any abilities that makes you airborn just like Blitzcrank Power Fist (E)

Comment: What about Alistar's headbutt?

Comment: Alistar's Headbutt stun the target for 1 second and then knock them back so  Master Yi will be stun and then airborn, stopping his Meditate